# Can I use Private Link between public subnet and private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'd like to connect an RDS in a private subnet from another EC2 in a public subnet of other AWS account.

I can connect the RDS from a private subnet of the other AWS account using PrivateLink.

But I cannot connect it from the public subnet of the other AWS account. I confirmed RDS, NLB, EndPoint Service, EndPoint and each security group.

Can I use Private Link between public subnet and private subnet?